# Jean-Pierre Serre's notation: $ \mathscr H_{x, U} $

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation, analytic-geometry, sheaf-theory

In $ \S $1 of Jean-Pierre Serre's article *Géométrie algébrique et géométrie analytique*, he uses notation that I have not seen in Hartshorne or Vakil or anywhere else: $\mathscr H_{x, U}$, where $\mathscr H$ is the sheaf of germs of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb C^n$. In my mind, $\mathscr H_{x, U} = \mathscr H_x$, and yet (as seen in the excerpt below) Serre talks about the *kernel* of
$$ \varepsilon_x : \mathscr H_x \to \mathscr H_{x, U} , $$
a notion I did not expect to exist. The relevant excerpt is below, with my thoughts at the end.

*Here, $\mathscr C(\mathbb C^n)$ denotes the sheaf of germs of functions on $\mathbb C^n$ with values in $\mathbb C$.*

> Soit alors $x$ un point de $U$; on a un homomorphisme de restriction
> $$ \varepsilon_x : \mathscr C(\mathbb C^n)_x \to \mathscr C(U)_x . $$
> L'image de $ \mathscr H_x $ par $ \varepsilon_x $ est un sous-anneau $ \mathscr H_{x, U}$ de $ \mathscr C(U)_x $; les $ \mathscr H_{x, U} $ forment un sous-faisceau $ \mathscr H_U $ de $ \mathscr C(U) $, que nous appellerons le *faisceau des germes de fonctions holomorphes sur $U$*; c'est un faisceau d'anneaux. Nous noterons $ \mathscr A_x(U) $ le noyau de $ \varepsilon_x : \mathscr H_x \to \mathscr H_{x, U} $; vu la définition de $ \mathscr H_{x, U} $, c'est l'ensemble des $ f \in \mathscr H_x $ dont la restriction à $U$ est nulle dans un voisinage de $x$; nous identifierons fréquemment $\mathscr H_{x, U}$ à l'anneau quotient $\mathscr H_x / \mathscr A_x(U)$.

An English translation I found online:

> So let $x$ be a point in $U$; we have a restriction
> $$ \varepsilon_x : \mathscr C(\mathbb C^n)_x \to \mathscr C(U)_x . $$
> The image of $\mathscr H_x$ under $\varepsilon_x$ is a subring $\mathscr H_{x, U}$ of $\mathscr C(U)_x$; the $\mathscr H_{x, U}$ form a subsheaf $\mathscr H_U$ of $\mathscr C(U)$, which we call the *sheaf of germs of holomorphic functions on $U$*; it is a sheaf of rings. We denote by $\mathscr A_x(U)$ the kernel of $\varepsilon_x : \mathscr H_x \to \mathscr H_{x, U}$; in light of the definition of $\mathscr H_{x, U}$, it is the set of $f \in \mathscr H_x$ whose restriction to $U$ is zero in a neighbourhood of $x$; we frequently identify $\mathscr H_{x, U}$ with the quotient ring $\mathscr H_x / \mathscr A_x(U)$.

I want to repackage this statement by applying the first isomorphism theorem to the exact sequence
$$
  \ker \varepsilon_x = \mathscr A_x(U)
  \to \mathscr H_x
  \to \mathscr H_{x, U}
  \to 0
$$
to get $\mathscr H_{x, U} \cong \mathscr H_x / \mathscr A_x(U)$, but I need to be precise about what exactly $\mathscr H_{x, U}$ and $\mathscr H_U$ denote. The restriction
$$
  \begin{align*}
    \mathscr H &\to \mathscr H_x
  \\
    f &\mapsto f_x
  \end{align*}
$$
makes sense, but what is
$$
  \begin{align*}
    \mathscr H_x &\to \mathscr H_{x, U}
  \\
    f_x &\mapsto \ ?
  \end{align*}
$$

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, $\mathscr H_{x, U}$ is what we would nowadays write as $(\mathscr H|_U)_x$, i.e. we restrict the sheaf $\mathscr H$ to the subset $U$, and then pass to the stalk at $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that $\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}} \newcommand{\scrH}{\mathscr{H}} \mathscr H$ is the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}^n$, while $\mathscr H_{U}$ (which he is in the process of defining) is the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $U$. So $\mathscr H_x$ consists of germs of functions on $\mathbb{C}^n$, meaning equivalence classes $[f,V]$ of pairs $(f,V)$ where $V \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ is open with $x \in V$, and $f: V \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic. As he has defined $\mathscr H_{x,U}$ to be the image $\varepsilon_x(\mathscr H_x)$ of $\scrH_x$ under $\varepsilon_x$, the map $\mathscr H_x \to \mathscr H_{x,U}$ is simply $\varepsilon_x$. More explicitly, given an equivalence class $[f,V] \in \scrH_x$, we have $\varepsilon_x([f,V]) = [f|_{V \cap U}, V \cap U]$.

An example might make this clearer. Suppose $n=2$, so $\mathscr H$ is the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}^2$, with coordinates $u,v$, and $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$ is the $u$-axis, defined by $v=0$. Then the restriction map $\varepsilon_x$ is basically given by $f(u,v) \mapsto f(u,0)$. There are many holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}^2$ that restrict to the same holomorphic function on $U$. For instance, the maps $u$, $u + 37v - 51v^5$, and $u - 42 \sin(v)$ all restrict to same function on $U$.

For a more extreme example, one could even take $U$ to just be a point. Let $U \subseteq \C$ be the singleton containing the origin: $U = \{0\}$. Letting $x = 0$, then $\scrH_{x,U} \cong \C$: the only nonempty open subset of $U = \{0\}$ is $U$ itself, so the map $[f, U] \mapsto f(0)$ is an isomorphism. By contrast, I claim that $\scrH_x$ is not a field. For instance, the function $f(z) = z$ has a nonzero germ at $0$ (it takes on nonzero values on any open neighborhood in $\mathbb{C}$ containing $0$), but its germ $[f,V] \in \scrH_x$ has no multiplicative inverse. (If $[g, W]$ were such an inverse, then we would have $1 = f(0) \, g(0) = 0 \cdot g(0) = 0$, contradiction.) Thus $\scrH_x$ is not a field, hence in particular is not isomorphic to $\C \cong \scrH_{x,U}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I see what Serre is trying to do. But to me, $[f, V]$ and $[f |_{V \cap U}, V \cap U]$ are, by definition, *the same object* since they agree on  $V \cap U$. The way I understand it, Serre is trying to capture all those (germs of) functions that ***can be*** equivalent to $0$ on $V \cap U$ (such as $v$ in your $\mathbb C^2$ example), but I don't know if these functions form a "true" kernel. After all, $\mathscr H_x = (\mathscr H |_U)_x$, no?

Comment: $U$ need not be open in $\mathbb{C}^n$. So while $V \cap U$ is open in $U$, it need not be open in $\mathbb{C}^n$. So $[f|_{V \cap U}, V \cap U]$ doesn't make sense as an element of $\mathscr{H}_x$. No, it is definitely *not* true that $\mathscr H_x = (\mathscr H |_U)_x$ in general. Consider the example I gave: is there an open neighborhood of $\mathbb{C}^2$ containing $x=(0,0)$ on which $u$ and $u+v$ coincide? Yet these functions are identical on the set $U$ where $v = 0$. Thus these represent distinct elements of $\mathscr{H}_x$, but represent the same element of $(\mathscr H |_U)_x$.

Comment: I've added details for another example with $U$ a singleton.